# Referral URL Window Application

Tags: asp.net, winforms, httpwebrequest

I have a situation where my web application is opened from a CRM (win-based application).

Can I get the name of the application through a request variable?  In a web application, the referral url works.  Is there something which I can explore?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way your web server is going to know which application opened the browser ... *unless* ... you give the application a different URL than normal traffic.  (Same method advertising campaigns use to tell who has been clicking on their ads.)  Have the desktop application use a URL with an added query parameter:

```
www.mywebsite.com/?source=mydesktopapplication
```

If this is impossible for you because you can't change the desktop app, then the only other (imperfect) thing I can think of is to assume that people with no referral URL are coming from the application.  The problem with this of course is that you will mistakenly identify visitors with no referral URL who still did not come from the desktop app, such as people who typed your website's URL into their address bar, or who clicked on a bookmarked link.